# Kafka Ktable breaks when using suppress to limit updates

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a streams application where I'm trying to aggregate a stream of events
and get a list of events per key.
I'm using `groupBy` coupled with windowed aggregation to create the List of events per key that occur within a time period.

I have custom `Serdes` implementations for my event and the `List<Event>`.

```
eventStream
.groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), eventSerde))
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(50)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(1)))
.aggregate(
    ArrayList::new, (event, accum) -> {
        accum.add(event);
        return accum;
})
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
.toStream()
.map((windowedKey, value) -> new KeyValue<String, List<Event>>(windowedKey.key(), value))
.map(eventProcessor::processEventsWindow)
.to("event-window-chunks-queue", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), eventListSerde))
```

As you can see I'm grouping events by key and capturing windowed lists of events for further processing.
To be able to process the list of events per key in chunks I added `suppress()`.
This does not seem to work though.
I get this error multiple times:

```
Got error produce response with correlation id 5 on topic-partition app-test143-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000016-changelog-0, retrying (2147483646 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender - Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition app-test143-KTABLE-SUPPRESS-STATE-STORE-0000000016-changelog-0 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.. Going to request metadata update now
```

**When I comment out the suppress() line it works fine** but I get a large number of events in a list while processing chunks since it does not suppress already evaluated chunks.

Can anyone help me out with what could be happening here?

Comment: You you check the broker logs? It should reveal more information why the broker closed the connection.